# Python multiple two identical dataframe to form a new dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, multiplication

I've 2 dataframes which look similar:

df1:

[image]

df2:

[image]

I want to update the column "length" in df1 by multiplying the values in df2 (for the "country" - "city" combination):

[image]

Did some Google, but could only find something like, merge or concat. Nothing like multiplying between dataframes.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Pandas Multiindex** feature is made for these kind of calculations. Re-index the dataframes to

```
df1 = df1.set_index(['country', 'city', 'road'])
df1 
                       length
country city    road    
us      ny      m1     10
                m2     20
        la      m3     30
                m4     40
                m5     50

df2 = df2.set_index(['country', 'city'])
df2
              length
country city    
us      ny    1
        la    2
```

and then **simply multiply** the 2 frames:

```
df1 = df1 * df2
df1
                      length
country city    road    
us      la      m3    60
                m4    80
                m5    100
        ny      m1    10
                m2    20
```

If you like you can of cause reset the index afterwards:

```
df1.reset_index()

country city    road    length
us      la      m3      60
us      la      m4      80
us      la      m5      100
us      ny      m1      10
us      ny      m2      20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first join in 2 dfs based on `country,city` to get both length1 and length2 in same df.

```
newdf = df1.merge(df2,on=["country","city"],how = "left")
```

then just multiply the two length columns you have.

*Rename one of the column `length.`Does not work if 2 columns have same name.*

Answer (score 0):

You could merge the columns based on country and city, then create a new column in which you calculate the new values and then update you dataframe:

```
# import df1
df1 = pd.read_excel(df1_from_directory)
df2 = pd.read_excel(df2_from_directory)


df1_test = df1
df2_test = df2

# merge the values from df1 basaed on city and country
df_merged = df1_test.merge(df2_test,on=["country","city"],how = "left")
df_merged

# create a new column in which you calculate the new values
df1_new_length = df_merged["df1_length"] * df_merged["length"]

# update the old column with the new values
df1_test.df1_length = df1_new_length

#
print(df1_test)
```

Worked for me.